# javascript method to accept a string or an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in the process of building a wrapper library for quite a large service so that the team that I'm working with has an easier time developing using this service.

Basically, one of the API calls is called "subscribe" so that the program subscribes to one or more items (in order to track its changes). The API call takes 1 argument. The documentation shows this:

- (string, required) Name identifier
- OR (string, required) ID identifier
- OR (array, optional) A JSON array of Name or ID identifiers

I did figure out how to use optional parameters, but I can't figure out to make an "either x or y" type of method in javascript.

Comment: You would need to check whether or not the passed argument is a string, or whether or not the passed argument is an array.

Comment: You can use `typeof parameter == 'string'` to check for strings and `parameter instanceof Array` or `Array.isArray(parameter)` to check for Arrays

Answer (score 1):

You could check the parameter and convert single value to an array and work with that array.

```js
function fn(parameter) {
    return (Array.isArray(parameter) ? parameter : [parameter]).map(a => 'item' + a);
}

console.log(fn(1));
console.log(fn('abc'));
console.log(fn([3, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler may be to make it a variadic function by using a "rest parameter". You could define two parameters, the first required and the rest parameter allowing zero or more.

```
function subscribe(item, ...items) {
  // item is required
  // items may be zero or more additional items
}
```

You don't actually need two parameters, except perhaps for documentation to more clearly show a required argument.

---

Then they can call it with individual arguments, or if they already have an array, they can use that using spread syntax.

```js
function subscribe(item, ...items) {
  console.log("Found: %s, Then: %s", item, items);
}

subscribe("one", "two", "three");

var my_items = ["one", "two", "three"];

subscribe(...my_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as in Java, you can write several prototypes of a method, each taking a different number of parameters. When called, the right method will be called by itself.

For example:

```
/* You must check if i is a String */
function method(i){
}

/* You must check if i is a String and j is an Array */
function method(i, j){
}
```

Now, concerning the type of the input, JavaScript doesn't check the type in the method prototype, unlike Java or C for example. Therefore, you need to control the type of your input inside the method.

You can use [isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method, or/and [TypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator when controlling the type.

Comment: Hmmm, What is "Same as in Java"? Why do you even mention java or c? :)

Comment: This is not going to work. We're required to use "standardjs" which doesn't like duplicate methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the input parameter for the string type of Array instance like this:

```js
function method(prm) {
 if (prm instanceof Array) {
   console.info("(array, optional) A JSON array of Name or ID identifiers");
    return;
  }
  
  if(typeof(prm) === "string") {
   console.info("Name identifier|ID identifier");
   return;
  }
  
  console.info("Unknown argument");
};

method("id");
method("name");
method(["id", "name"]);
method(1);
```